# Automatically detect if the system date has changed

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to start a countdown timer whenever system date has changed or the user has changed the system date manually. I have used **[this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)** broadcast action to detect if the system date has changed but it's not working. There are lot of threads on this issue. Some users are saying that it only works when user changes the date manually from settings and some users are saying that it works in both ways i.e date gets changed automatically or user changes it manually from settings. But in my case it's not working in both of the cases. Some users are suggesting to use Alarm Manager instead of this broadcast action i.e "android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED".

Following is my implementation of the broadcast:

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.byteshaft.a1440time">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".receivers.OnDateChangeReceiver"  android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My broadcast receiver class:

```
    public class OnDateChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED)){
            System.out.println("Changed");
        }
    }
}
```

If Alarm Manager is the only solution then is there any guide on how to implement it in a proper way?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to get notified only if the time of the device is set ?

You can listen on the `android.intent.action.TIME_SET` broadcast instead.
It is triggered everytime the system time is modified.

If your app is targeting Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher this broadcast cannot be registered in the AndroidManifest.xml , it can only be registered via `Context.registerBroadcastReceiver`

Comment: I need to get notified whenever system date gets changed.

Comment: @Dominik `android.intent.action.TIME_SET` is a whitelisted intent, and can be set in Manifest, even in API 26, as per https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html

Answer (score 1):

For detect changes of date you have to use two intent actions:

```
    <receiver android:name=".BroadcastReceiverTest">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I tested and it works.

During target the API level 26 or higher, you can not use `"android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED"` for implicit broadcasts in manifest.